# Cannot get value from local storage inside function without converting to async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous

I have made a wrapper for fetch function for my API calls in react-native. I dont want to pass JWT token everytime that I make an API call, so I thought that fetching it inside wrapper will fix it for me, but I cannot get it to work because of async nature...

useFetch.js

```
// import qs from "querystring";
import { getUserAuthToken } from "../storage";

const responseChecker = async (response) => {
  let error = "";
  let data = {};
  let statusCode = null;
  if (!response.ok) {
    error = "Something went wrong";
    statusCode = response.status;
  } else {
    statusCode = response.status;
    data = await response.json();
  }
  return { statusCode, error, data };
};

const fetchAuthToken = getUserAuthToken();

const useFetch = (baseURL, authHeader = null) => {
  console.log(fetchAuthToken);
  **//Cannot get this token in time for the API call ^**
  const defaultHeader = {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    key: "1c419c7e-3a34-49f0-9192-b48d4534dff3",
    Authorization: authHeader ? authHeader :fetchAuthToken,
  };

  const customFetch = (
    url,
    method = "GET",
    body = false,
    headers = defaultHeader,
  ) => {
    const options = {
      method,
      headers,
      credentials: "include",
    };
    if (body) options.body = body;
    return fetch(url, options);
  };
  const get = async (endpoint) => {
    const url = `${baseURL}${endpoint}`;
    const response = await customFetch(url, "GET");
    return responseChecker(response);
  };
  const post = async (endpoint, body = {}) => {
    const url = `${baseURL}${endpoint}`;
    const response = await customFetch(url, "POST", body);
    return responseChecker(response);
  };
  const put = async (endpoint, body = {}) => {
    const url = `${baseURL}${endpoint}`;
    const response = await customFetch(url, "PUT", body);
    return responseChecker(response);
  };
  return {
    get,
    post,
    put,
  };
};
export default useFetch;
```

storage.js

```
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage";
export const getUserAuthToken = async () => {
  try {
    const userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userAuthToken");
    return userToken;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("error");
  }
};
```

exportAPI.js

```
import useFetch from "./fetch";
const LOCAL_IP = "192.168.0.131";
export const authAPI = (header) => useFetch(`http://${LOCAL_IP}:8000`, header);
export const activityAPI = useFetch(`http://${LOCAL_IP}:8000`);
```

Steps.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Text, Platform } from "react-native";
import { CardXLarge } from "../../../components/Cards/";
import fitnessKitApis from "../../../utilities/fitnessKits";
import { activityAPI } from "../../../utilities/apis";

const StepCard = (props) => {
  const fetchStepsFromFitnessKits = async () => {
    if (Platform.OS === "android") {
      await fitnessKitApis.historicSteps().then((res) => {
        setSteps(res);
      });
    } else {
      await fitnessKitApis.historicSteps((result) => setSteps(result));
    }
  };

  const [steps, setSteps] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchStepsFromFitnessKits();
    const requestParams = { date: new Date(), steps };
    const { data, statusCode, error } = activityAPI.get(
      "/v1/user/steps/",
      requestParams,
    );
    // console.log(data, statusCode, error);
  }, [steps]);
  return (
    <CardXLarge>
      <Text>{steps}</Text>
    </CardXLarge>
  );
};

export default StepCard;
```

I know I can pass authHeader from component but that will result in adding 2-3 lines of code in every component which is not super convenient.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved getUserAuthToken function down to each request method function in useFetch function where I can await for the response. Then it all worked perfectly.. Also I could have use getUserAuthToken but usingAsyncStorage.getItem seems much cleaner

modified fetch.js

```
// import qs from "querystring";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage";

const responseChecker = async (response) => {
  let error = "";
  let data = {};
  let statusCode = null;
  if (!response.ok) {
    error = "Something went wrong";
    statusCode = response.status;
  } else {
    statusCode = response.status;
    data = await response.json();
  }
  return { statusCode, error, data };
};

const useFetch = (baseURL, authHeader = null) => {
  const defaultHeader = {
    Accept: "application/json",
    // "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    key: "1c419c7e-3a34-49f0-9192-b48d4534dff3",
    Authorization: authHeader,
  };

  const customFetch = (
    url,
    method = "GET",
    body = false,
    headers = defaultHeader,
  ) => {
    const options = {
      method,
      headers,
      credentials: "include",
    };
    if (body) options.body = JSON.stringify(body);
    return fetch(url, options);
  };
  const get = async (endpoint) => {
    await AsyncStorage.getItem("userAuthToken").then((result) => {
      defaultHeader.Authorization = result;
    });
    const url = `${baseURL}${endpoint}`;
    const response = await customFetch(url, "GET");
    return responseChecker(response);
  };
  const post = async (endpoint, body = {}) => {
    await AsyncStorage.getItem("userAuthToken").then((result) => {
      defaultHeader.Authorization = result;
    });
    const url = `${baseURL}${endpoint}`;
    const response = await customFetch(url, "POST", body);
    return responseChecker(response);
  };
  const put = async (endpoint, body = {}) => {
    await AsyncStorage.getItem("userAuthToken").then((result) => {
      defaultHeader.Authorization = result;
    });
    const url = `${baseURL}${endpoint}`;
    const response = await customFetch(url, "PUT", body);
    return responseChecker(response);
  };
  return {
    get,
    post,
    put,
  };
};
export default useFetch;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use async/await in a function to get items from asyncStorage. You can use either callback or promise in place of async/await.

Callback:

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('data1', (error, data1) => {
  // perform your logic here.
});
```

Promise:

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('data1').then(data1=>{
 // perform your logic here.
}).catch(error=>{
 // handle error
})
```

I have personally used callback for getItem and worked perfectly. I have not tested the promise version but I expect to do the same work as callback.

Comment: `
AsyncStorage.getItem("userAuthToken", (error, result) => {
      console.log("here");
      defaultHeader.Authorization = result;
    });
`
Added this in useFetch.js in useFetch function still not working,,,

Answer (score 0):

```
...
const fetchAuthToken = getUserAuthToken();
...
```

Your `getUserAuthToken` is an asynchronous function and here it is not being awaited. To guarantee that asynchronous call is finished you have to await it or use callbacks as @HungrySoul suggested.

You can't await something outside of an asynchronous function.

Solution that I would suggest is creating a `class UseFetch` and passing the arguments through the constructor. The argument being here the JWT token that you are getting from the `AsyncStorage`.

Also, another thing that can be done and is a good practice - use `redux` for managing the state and keeping the JWT token. You might look into that. It will take a bit longer but it will make your code more elegant.

Edit: Or, you might try something like this.

Keep in mind that you have to wait for promises to resolve before you use what was promised.

Here we are using a closure. You will have to pass an argument (which is an `async function`) to the `useFetchBuilder`. That function will be awaited and provide the JWT. You can use the `getUserAuthToken` for that purpose.

Keep in mind that you have to use await or wait for the promise to resolve before using this function. Problem might be somewhere else in your code - maybe the life cycle methods.

I hope this helped.

```
const responseChecker = async (response) => {
  let error = "";
  let data = {};
  let statusCode = null;
  if (!response.ok) {
    error = "Something went wrong";
    statusCode = response.status;
  } else {
    statusCode = response.status;
    data = await response.json();
  }
  return { statusCode, error, data };
};


const useFetchBuilder = async (userTokenProvider) => {
  const userToken = await userTokenProvider();

  return (baseURL, authHeader = null) => {

    const defaultHeader = {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      key: "1c419c7e-3a34-49f0-9192-b48d4534dff3",
      Authorization: authHeader ? authHeader : userToken,
    };

    const customFetch = (
      url,
      method = "GET",
      body = false,
      headers = defaultHeader,
    ) => {
      const options = {
        method,
        headers,
        credentials: "include",
      };
      if (body) options.body = body;
      return fetch(url, options);
    };
    const get = async (endpoint) => {
      const url = `${baseURL}${endpoint}`;
      const response = await customFetch(url, "GET");
      return responseChecker(response);
    };
    const post = async (endpoint, body = {}) => {
      const url = `${baseURL}${endpoint}`;
      const response = await customFetch(url, "POST", body);
      return responseChecker(response);
    };
    const put = async (endpoint, body = {}) => {
      const url = `${baseURL}${endpoint}`;
      const response = await customFetch(url, "PUT", body);
      return responseChecker(response);
    };
    return {
      get,
      post,
      put,
    };
  };
}

export default useFetchBuilder;
```

Comment: In class and redux approach, I will have to write additional code to pass this token, where as I want it to automatically pickup whenever I make an API call.

Comment: @GauravSaini Check out the new approach in the edit. Hope it helps.

Comment: Could you please explain how to use this in exportAPI.js
@Shocky2

Comment: Thanks for the help, I posted my solution, please check and comment on that...